# Can you tell which percussion instrument this is?

Tags: instrument

(I didn't find the song on youtube neither on soundcloud so spotify it is.)

I just want to know which percurssive element is this, so i can find a sample of it or a library.

The sound plays at 0:30 (it's not the kick of course), it's the sound that has some low-mid/high-mid focus and has a lot of stereo image. (The name of the song is "lips" by "The XX" in case the link doesn't work)

https://open.spotify.com/album/2PXy9USZAoTSdtrxfkPBnl

Comment: I'm not on Spotify and the song is restricted on YT. That just makes me more curios about these drums or whatever they are :<

Answer (score 1):

Tongue drum? Lots of videos on YouTube under that heading. Sounds a bit more wood than metal otherwise a Hang drum might be a possibility. The drone is a bit didgeridooish.

Could also be something like a Boomwhacker. Tons of them on YouTube and lots of sample libraries. E.g. https://www.wavesfactory.com/boomwhackers/ .

Another element in there sounds a bit like a clave, the instrument not the pattern, as well.

Comment: Could also be a processed marimba, but seems less likely. With electronic samples libraries, listening under "marimba" might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Kalimba is my best answer for you.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbira)

Comment: Hi Ray, can you please expand this answer with a link to sound or video.

Comment: If only there was a way for you to tell us what a Kalimba is, how it's used,  what it does and what it's history is.

Answer (score 0):

It could be some bongo drums which have been slightly altered: corse tuned down a bit + a tiny touch of delay + compression with fast release, to give that something of "xylo" sound.

But indeed this is pure speculation...

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a Thai traditional wooden xylophone, the small one about a foot long